# Let a .NET core application run as a service on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services

I am trying to let a .NET core application run as a service, but i can't figure it out, because it is not my type of software i normally run on an Ubuntu server.

Each time when i close my console the application stops and i would like it to run as a service. I am using the command "dotnet run" and tried to use a command as a cronjob, but that does not seem to work.

Is it even possible to let a .NET core application as a service on Ubuntu?

Comment: Why don't you configure your init system to run the application as daemon? Are you trying to just run the application "in background"?

Comment: Can you add it to startup applications? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your application running in background after closing terminal, you could use something like [gnu screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).

Running as system daemon you need to configure your init system (in ubuntu likely [systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) or [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)).